# Do i need to change my SQL-Statements in my VB5/VB.net-Application, if i change the used database from Access 97 to Access 365?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, jet, vb5

I have many legacy applications. Some in VB5, some in VB.net. They all use SQL-Statements in the Source-Code, using a Access97-Database-File. We want to upgrade to Access365.
Is the Syntax between Access97 and Access365 different?
If so, are there any automated tools?

Thank you very much

Comment: "Access 365" does not denote a specific build or version of Office Access. Anyway, **no**: Access's (JET Red) dialect of SQL is really unchanged since Access 2002 (and even then, it was mostly frozen by Access 97): you're stuck on a subset of ANSI SQL-92. I have no reason why Microsoft has abandoned desktop Access like this.

Comment: Tangent, but would suggest if you're porting a VB5 app now is a really good time to do a total review on the back end RDBMS.  Changes are likely going to have to be relatively large as is so could be an opportune time to move to something like SQL server